# mail sending issue in PHP

Tags: php

I just tried mail sending in php. There is no error messages and also show sucess message.but no mail should be get in receipts mail.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Well,I run it in localhost

Comment: I checked the previous issues asked by someones and tried all the solutions said in it. Yet not working.Dats why I asked the same.

Answer (score 0):

With Your Email have you check the Junk/Spam Folder as you are sending the mail from an unregistered domain name (localhost) which my trigger the Gmail spam filters. Also try and send a CC to a temperary mail address.

Can you also provide what smtp server you are using or package such as xamp or wamp etc...

Comment: ya..i checked spam folder too

Comment: Have You tried sending a carbon copy of the email to and tempery address?

Comment: Could you give me your smtp server name and web server name + version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Mail Transport Agent (MTA), or if you like, a SMTP service installed/configured? Otherwise you can't send e-mails from your localhost.